# What actions towards Force.com canvas limits?

Tags: canvas

I'm looking to integrate an external web application into salesforce via connected app/canvas approach. As per project requirements, there will be 10+ visualstudio pages or lightning components that expose the canvas app, passing parameters that will be used to serve the correct page in our web app.

I'm a total sf beginner, and I came across some information about canvas limits:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_limits.htm

Number of Force.com Canvas calls per day per user (24–hour period):
5,000
This includes SDK calls to get context and signed request calls. Note that when you call a SignedRequest method, there are actually two calls that are made—one call for the method and one call for internal logging.

I'm concerned about high-frequency users approaching this limit, but I'm a little unclear on what a "canvas call" includes.

1. Does anybody have an understanding of how many calls get made when the canvas app is rendered and authenticated via signed request?
2. If I publish events from a canvas app into the visualforce page, do these also count towards the limit?
3. Is it accurate to say that all Force.com limits are unrelated to product/edition?